# Is there a difference between name decoration/mangling and attribute decoration?

Tags: c#

I've been reading a text about an extension to C# and at one point it says that "An attribute decoration X may only be applied to fields of type Y."

I haven't been able to find a definition for attribute decoration, and I'm not making much sense out of this by exchanging the two.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably referring to the Attribute class. For example, you can mark a type as serializable via the SerializableAttribute. When you apply an attribute, you can leave off the "Attribute" suffix.

```
[Serializable]
public class SomeClass {

}
```

Attributes provide a means to add meta-data about the code.

Answer (score 1):

Attributes are used to add metadata to .NET (C#) code in a structured manner. What a lot of people don't realise, though, is that there are actually *two types* of attribute.

The simplest is custom attributes, where you define an attribute that specific classes look for to alter the way they work. A common example is the `System.Xml.Serialization` attributes which are read by the `XmlSerializer` to alter its output, e.g. a class could be marked up something like the following to specify its namespace and that the field should be an attribute:

```
[XmlType(Namespace = "http://mycompany.com/")]
public class MyClass
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string MyField;
}
```

Custom attributes like this have no meaning to the compiler or the runtime, they are just added to the class as part of its metadata, and can be retrieved by a call to `Type.GetCustomAttributes`.

The other main group of attributes is pseudo-custom attributes, which actually have meaning to either the compiler or the runtime. The example in the post by **Haacked** with `SerializableAttribute` is actually an example of a pseudo-custom attribute. It is actually stored as part of the type definition and cannot be retrieved using `Type.GetCustomAttributes`. You cannot create your own pseudo-custom attributes.

So it's likely what you're dealing with here is a custom attribute which is being looked for by a specific tool.